# Image in header shows in Word for Desktop but disappears in Word Online

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I use `insertHtml` inserted an online image in my header, however, it only works on a desktop. When I go back to edit the document online the image doesn't show correctly. The image frame shows in the correct spot, but not the actual image.

Can someone explain?

```
myHeader.insertHtml(
  '<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/32/CGI_logo.svg/1200px-CGI_logo.svg.png" alt="logo" height="42" width="42" align="right"/>',
  "End"
);
```

Comment: I can reproduce the issue in Word Online. Image doesn't display in either Edge or Chrome. I find that if I open the header for editing, the image DOES display in the editor. Do you get that too? At any rate, if you don't get an answer in a few days, open an issue on this repo: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues (This should ONLY be done after you've tried to get help on StackOverflow and only if the problem looks like a probably bug.)

Comment: Thank you Rick for your fast reply. I'll see if someone else can help and maybe open an issue on github later. I'm not complaining but seems it seems developing office addin is so troublesome, because office Js sometimes works differently for office online and desktop. For example I tried insertInlinePictureFromBase64() method to insert a base64 formatted image, it only works online but not on desktop.

Answer (score 1):

It is not related to office.js.

Word Online does not show header by default.
You need to edit the header or footer to see your image.

You will not see pages breaks or anything like this.